customise Prechat in salesforce MIAW
We are tying to replace live chat with MIAW in experience community. Is there a way to override standard prechat form in MIAW. We have done in live chat but not happening Messaging in web. We couldn't find any reference article or trailhead.
Has anyone worked on it?

Did you try below link? It shows LWC option to customize
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/service/messaging-web/guide/create-custom-pre-chat-form.html

Yes, it is possible to override the standard pre-chat form in Messaging for In-App and Web (MIAW) using Lightning Web Components (LWC). Salesforce provides a way to create a custom pre-chat form for MIAW, which allows you to customize the user interface and functionality.
To create a custom pre-chat form using LWC for MIAW, follow these steps:

Create an LWC bundle for your custom pre-chat form.
In the component’s meta XML file, specify the lightningSnapin__MessagingPreChat target.
Implement the HTML, JavaScript, and CSS files for your custom pre-chat form.
Create a separate LWC bundle for defining the pre-chat fields.
Deploy the LWCs to your Salesforce org.
Add the custom LWC to your Embedded Service Deployment in Setup.

Key points to consider:

The custom pre-chat form can display the pre-chat fields configured
in Embedded Service Deployments in Setup.

You need to implement a dispatchEvent function in your JavaScript file to handle form submission.

The custom LWC allows you to control the rendering and
styling of pre-chat fields.


By following these steps, you can replace the standard pre-chat form with a custom one in your MIAW implementation for your Experience Cloud community
he documentation is here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/service/messaging-web/guide/create-custom-pre-chat-form.html

Can you post the relevant content from the link here? Even Salesforce break their links over time

This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker. - From Review
